# AS3-Copy the transparency from 1 BitmapData object(loaded PNG) and apply to another?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I have a problem involving loading transparent pngs.
What I am trying to do, is to copy the alpha channel from a loaded png, and then apply this alpha channel to another Bitmapdata object.

Can anyone suggest how I would do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, I have a class that does exactly that:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.BitmapDataChannel;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class BitmapAlphaMerge
    {
        public static function merge (imgBitmap:Bitmap, maskBitmap:Bitmap) : Bitmap
        {
            var img:BitmapData = imgBitmap.bitmapData;
            var mask:BitmapData = maskBitmap.bitmapData;
            var mergeBmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.width, img.height, true, 0);
            var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            mergeBmp.copyPixels(img, rect, new Point());
            mergeBmp.copyChannel(mask, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.width, img.height), new Point(), BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA, BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);
            return new Bitmap(mergeBmp);
        }
    }
}
```

The first parameter `imgBitmap` is the image you want to add the alpha channel to. `maskBitmap` is the Bitmap you are copying the channel from. You could modify this to use pure BitmapData objects quite easily.